Multipatch object texture raster analysis using ArcGIS Pro
Is there a way to treat a multipatch's texture/skin as an ordinary raster and do raster algebra on it using ArcGIS Pro?
I have a number of objects I'm working with that I've exported from Rhino as multipatches into ArcGIS Pro via .obj and .dae. It would be great if they were treatable as standalone raster layers but I cannot see how to do that.

This sounds like an enhancement request, a particularly unworkable one -- What would happen if the multipatch's surface is angled down?

@Vince the idea was to treat the model import as static and just do some analysis on the texture/image skin of the model - not dynamic. For collada exports that come with texture, the image file is colocated in the zip rather than being embedded in dae file itself, so I just thought there might be a way for ArcGIS to treat it as any other raster image (thats just been draped over the 3d object). Perhaps not however
